# Sql query to find averages of past values

Tags: oracle

I have some data that logs a value (volume) in regular hourly intervals throughout the day to an oracle sql database. I am looking for an sql query that can find the average volume from occurrences in the past so I can insert that into a new table based on that time in the past. For example, for every Wednesday at 7pm for as long as my dataset goes back, I want to find what the average was at that time for all Wednesdays at 7pm in the past, and output the average to a new record. Then find the average recording for Wednesdays at 8pm , then 9pm and so forth, until all 7 days in a week are complete.

I am primarily unsure of how to increment this in sql. I *think* I have a query that will return what I want, but I am unsure of how to increment the values and insert.

So far I have this for a particular hour of a particular day:

```
SELECT hour,day,AVG(volume)
FROM table
WHERE to_char(day, 'D') = 3 and hour = 19
GROUP BY hour,day;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to run the above query for all combinations of day and hour.

This query gives all such combinations.

```
  SELECT ds, LPAD (hrs, 2, '0') hrs
    FROM (    SELECT LEVEL ds
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7),
         (    SELECT LEVEL - 1 hrs
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24)
ORDER BY ds, hrs;
```

So, your query should be something like this.

**EDIT**:

```
INSERT INTO avg_table (days, hours, avrg)
   WITH xweek
        AS (SELECT ds, LPAD (hrs, 2, '0') hrs
              FROM (    SELECT LEVEL ds
                          FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7),
                   (    SELECT LEVEL - 1 hrs
                          FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24))
     SELECT t1.ds, t1.hrs, AVG (volume)
       FROM xweek t1, tables t2
      WHERE     t1.ds = TO_CHAR (t2.day(+), 'D')
            AND t1.hrs = t2.hour(+)
   GROUP BY t1.ds, t1.hrs;
```

I have formed xweek, which returns all combinations of day and hour(24 * 7). Outer joining this with table in question, i get avg values for all combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks pretty good. The day is stored as a timestamp and the hour value is separate. Do you have any advice on inserting these values into a table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `day` is of type `DATE`

Try something like this:

```
SELECT hour,to_char(day, 'D'), AVG(volume)
FROM table
WHERE to_char(day, 'D') = 3 and hour = 19
GROUP BY hour,to_char(day, 'D');
```

BTW, you might cosider using

```
to_char(day, 'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'wed'
```

instead of

```
to_char(day, 'D') = 3
```

So your query won't rely on nls parameters which might deffer on different environments
[See example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11447)